# redirect to a page which is updated

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two pages: a search page and an edit page (jsp files). The search page is used to search and display a list of Projects. The edit page is used to edit a project.

In the search page I have a link to the project number which is used to navigate to the edit page.

When users edited successfully a project, they will be redirected to the search page.

My question is how to make the search page show the up-to-date project immediately without refresh or search again? I'm using hibernate + spring mvc.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far if you go through a few tutorials should figure it out .

Comment: Your problem description is missing important information about how your UI is supposed to work.  What needs to be refreshed?  The search form?  The search results?

Comment: are you using annotations bases spring mvc?

Answer (score 0):

I think it does the work. Passing the search pattern to the edit action through the session. So you have it available the time you redirect to the search page to display the updated seach results.

```
@Controller
public class ProjectsController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String doEditProject(HttpSession httpSession, @ModelAttribute Project p ) {

        //  persist the edited project

        // redirect to search page with last search word
        String searchPattern = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("search_pattern");
        return "redirect:search?pattern=" + searchPattern;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String displaySearch(@RequestParam(value = "pattern", required = false) String searchPattern, ModelMap model, HttpSession httpSession) {

        if (searchPattern == null) {
            // display empty search view
            return "searchView";
        } else {

            //  search using the pattern
            // put model and create links like edit?project_id=xx
            httpSession.setAttribute("search_pattern", searchPattern);
            return "searchView";
        }
    }



}
```